# SQL Server installation error SQLCLI component

Tags: sql-server, sqlclient

I am trying to install SQL Server 2016 but getting error on installing SQL Server Native Client, I have tried installing SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 RC well but all are failing on installing client comopnet. I get following error.

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Can anybody help how can I fix this issue?
Only SQL Server 2008 R2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/get-error-1723-there-is-a-problem-with-windows/3d68fc4b-c968-4796-a270-27027a52de3f)

> I had the exact same problem. The solution is to go into 
>      c:\users\"username"\AppData\Local\  then right click on "temp" and choose 
>      "properies". Choose "security" --> edit --> add, and add the username you 
>      are using, and give yourself all rights. After that it'll work :)

Another suggestion is to re-install the installer.  You can do that [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483).

Comment: I have given everyone full access but still not working.